# application of vectors: parachute in the wind

Tags: calculus, vectors

Parachute in the wind. In still air, a parachute with a payload would fall vertically at terminal speed of 4 m/s. Find the direction and magnitude of its terminal velocity relative to the ground if it falls in a stead wind blowing horizontally west to east at 10 m/s.

So I went about this problem by drawing a right triangle. I had 10 m/s be the horizontal component and 4 m/s be the vertical component. I applied the pythagorean theorem and found the magnitude of its terminal velocity relative to the ground to be 10.8 m/s.

Then to find the direction I did intense tangent for the horizontal and vertical components and got 21.8 degrees. I am just now very confused how I find the direction like is it North of east, South of east..etc. Can someone please explain step by step?

Answer (score 0):

We are adding two vectors which are perpendicular to each other; one with magnitude $4$ and direction downwards and the other with magnitude $10$ and direction eastward.

You are correct in drawing the right triangle and the magnitude calculation, but perhaps it would help to understand **where** the triangle is drawn to find the direction. Let us examine the right triangle with the eastward vector and a translation of the downward vector east as legs. Using basic trigonometry, we find the angle is $\arctan\left(\frac{4}{10}\right),$ which is about $21.8$ degrees. Looking at the triangle, we see that this angle is **below** east, since the parachute is losing altitude.

Our final answer is $\boxed{21.8^{\circ}}$ **below east** at a speed of $\boxed{10.8\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}}.$